# Android app to share a canvas so that multiple user can draw arcs simultaneously

Tags: android, canvas

Hi I am developing an android app in which a canvas is shared between multiple users so that they can draw arcs simultaneously on it. My plan was to use phonegap so that I can use HTML5 canvas element. But I am finding it bit difficult to do by this way. Are there other (easy) way to built this app means without using phonegap. Please share some other alternative approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an architecture where you store everybodys strokes in an object that is shared between all drawers.

Say you have an object like this:

```
public class DrawStrokes{
 private ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> strokes;
}
```

Then you can add methods to add strokes (`ArrayList<Point>`), and add methods to receive all strokes aswell.

When you draw the strokes, just get all ArrayLists and draw them.

The object can ofcourse become more complex by adding colours and such.

Edit: More code on implementation.

Receive touch events:

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        synchronized (drawThread.getSurfaceHolder()) {
            final int action = e.getAction();
            switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    startNewArrayOfDrawingPoints();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    addPositionToYourArray();

                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    userStoppedDrawing();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                    userStoppedDrawing();
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Draw everything in your list

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            for(int i = 0; i < allStrokes.size(); i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < allStrokes.get(i).size(); j++){
                canvas.drawCircle(allStrokes.get(i).get(j).x, 
                            allStrokes.get(i).get(j).y, 
                            radie, 
                            paint;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you give approach how to implement a canvas in which user can draw anything using touch. I need just an approach, I am new to android